# Customized ivr web applications

Tags: asp.net, ivr, vxml

do any customized web applications exists, which facilitates user to build their own customized ivr. So any one kindly provide links? or any tutorial available to build customized ivr web application?

Answer (score 0):

Most IVR vendors provide Eclipse based IVR designing tools.
For a web app based you can try voxeo prophecy engine, it is free to try with 2 IVR ports and web based IVR designing tool.

[voxeo-prophecy](https://voxeo.com/products/voxeo-prophecy/)

It supports:

1. VXML2.1
2. CCXML
3. SCXML
4. TTS
5. ASR